# nodeclipse Enide, delete keyword issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodeclipse, enide

[image]

how come there appears to be a syntax error on "delete"? the same thing happens when I make HTTP delete requests explicitly. Is there something wrong with my Enide installation? This must be a known problem.

the same issue appears here:

[image]

Comment: Is this problem solved somehow? I am experiencing the same, also have the problem when I use CATCH keyword.

Comment: Hi Milos - I love Eclipse - but for Node.js I moved to Webstorm..Webstorm is pretty solid but it costs $50 USD.

Comment: i think delete is a keyword in JS for deleting properties from vars...but x.delete should not engage the syntax parser...idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue [#70](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/70) EcmaScript 5 support (Express server.delete - Syntax error on token ".")

Nodeclipse uses JSDT Editor, that does not support EcmaScript 5
 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=223131

Nodeclipse also has non-default TextEditor-based Editor.

Implementing EcmaScript 5 or general JavaScript Editor is huge task that Nodeclipse needs more resources to approach.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick fix for this problem, disabled 
"Strict validation of JavaScript keywords usage".

Now I am able to code again. :)